# How do you update a windows package using puppet, when older version is previously installed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, puppet, aws-cli

my puppet module is able to install the msi provided no problem on any windows machine. However the issue is, when I go to update the module and put in a newer version, it stays on the previous version instead of installing the newer version. Here's the block

```
   package { 'AWS Command Line Interface':
       ensure          => "${awscli_version_for_install_windows}",
       provider        => 'windows',
       source          => "c:\windows\temp\AWSCLI_${awscli_version_for_install_windows}.msi",
       install_options => ['/qn', '/norestart', '/l*v', 'c:\windows\temp\awscli.log'],
     }
```

Comment: It should as the package has the feature `versionable`, unless the `aws-cli` doesn't show properly the `version` in installed software. Does your version provided through `${awscli_version_for_install_windows}` matches the version displayed in `Add remove software` ?

Comment: Is there a page for the previous releases of `aws-cli` (not only the [`latest`](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi))? Something similar to an *Archive* or *Releases* page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys so I actually found out the fix. In the install_options command you need to include “REINSTALLMODE=AMUS”

```
package { 'AWS Command Line Interface':
       ensure          => "${awscli_version_for_install_windows}",
       provider        => 'windows',
       source          => "c:\windows\temp\AWSCLI_${awscli_version_for_install_windows}.msi",
       install_options => ['/qn', ‘REINSTALLMODE=AMUS’, '/norestart', '/l*v', 'c:\windows\temp\awscli.log'],
 }
```